# Using a Haystack Result within Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I am filtering userprofiles via their interests using Haystack. How can I use Haystack's result to query a model to return me all selected users belonging to these userprofiles?

Right now I am doing it the following way, but it is really slow, as haystack_results can be a list of many thousands of entries:

```
haystack_results = SearchQuerySet().raw_search('coffee AND django_ct:common.profile').values_list('pk', flat=True)
User.objects.filter(profile__id__in=haystack_results)
```

User and Profile have a OneToOne Relationship:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(...)
```

Do you know any better way?

Thanks for your help,
Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of the following:

1. Add a separate `SearchIndex` indexing the `User` model using the data from `Profile` (and query using `.models(User)`)
2. Add a [stored data field](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#stored-indexed-fields) to your `ProfileIndex` (I'm assuming that's what you named it), storing the `profile`'s `.user_id`. Use that in your `values_list`, and `profile__id__in` becomes `id__in`.
3. Wait for [`load_all`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#load-all) to support prefetching related data (unlikely to happen soon)
4. Have your `Profile` [inherit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) from `User`. Note: I do not know for sure if Django does a join each time, or a lazy load once a parent field is requested.